# Evaluate expression using yield statements

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, yield

I have a list with measurements `Measurements(100, 0.3)`.

I am supplying these measurements to the Criteria class `Criteria(999, [Measurements(100, 0.3), Measurements(33, 0.5)])` in order to apply some criteria to the measurements (the `method` function in `Criteria` class).

Then, I  have a list (Evaluate) which contains all the above (corrected values) but can run for a list of `Criteria`.So, I am supplying a list of Criteria to it.

Finally, I have a `General` class where I am supplying a list of `Evaluate` .

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy
from sympy import symbols, sympify
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import ufuncify
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

class Measurements():
    def __init__(self, value, other):
        self.value = value
        self.other = other


class Criteria():
    def __init__(self, new_value, measurements):
        self.new_value = new_value
        self.measurements = measurements

    def method(self):
        for measurement in self.measurements:
            if 20 < measurement.value < 110:
                measurement.value = self.new_value
        return self.measurements

class Evaluate():
    def __init__(self, name, criteria):
        self.name = name
        self.criteria = criteria

    def execute(self):
        for c in self.criteria:
            c.method()
            yield c.measurements

class General():
    def __init__(self, expression, evaluate):
        self.expression = expression
        self.evaluate = evaluate

    def proc(self):

        for element in self.evaluate:
            yield element.execute()





evaluate = [
    Evaluate('a',
             [
                 Criteria(999, [Measurements(100, 0.3), Measurements(33, 0.5)]),
                 Criteria(999, [Measurements(150, 0.3), Measurements(35, 0.5)])
             ]),

     Evaluate('b',
             [
                 Criteria(999, [Measurements(100, 0.3), Measurements(33, 0.5)]),
                 Criteria(999, [Measurements(150, 0.3), Measurements(35, 0.5)])
             ])
]
```

At this point of code everything works ( I can get back the correct measurements results, which are :

```
[Measurements(999, 0.3), Measurements(999, 0.5)],
[Measurements(150, 0.3), Measurements(999, 0.5)]
```

)
So , the `Measurements value` has changed to 999,999,150,999.

Now I want to do the following.

I want to be able to get the result array of `Evaluate('a',..)` and the result array of `Evaluate('b',...)` , pass them to `General.proc()` method and evaluate some expression (for example `a+b`).

I want to distinguish between 'a' and 'b' results because the expression may be `a*8+b` or `a+b*8` for example.

I know that in the `sympy` part, I have to do something like:

```
def proc(self):
    a, b = symbols("data_a data_b")
    expression = sympify(self.expression)

    for element in self.evaluate:
            yield element.execute()

    f = ufuncify((a, b), expression, backend='numpy')
    yield f(data_a, data_b)
```

But I don't know how to fill the parts  (as I said I must have the results of a and b separately, so in the above code `data_a` will be the result for a and `data_b` the result for b.